# Odd behavior to geom_smooth function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been reading a lot of the post associated to `geom_smooth()` and I think this is a new question, if not please link the solution and I will read that one!

I have a data set we are comparing qPCR detection results over the course of 30 days

```
ggplot(Vaccine1, aes(x= factor(DPV),y = VAC1)) + 
geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center",dotsize = .5) +
scale_y_reverse() + 
expand_limits(y=c(15,40))
```

This gives me the graph want, the detection trend/sampling day
[image: Detection vs Day]

When I call the above code with `geom_smooth()` I get the same plot with out the line.

```
ggplot(Vaccine1, aes(x= factor(DPV),y = VAC1)) + 
geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center",dotsize = .5) +
scale_y_reverse() + 
expand_limits(y=c(15,40)) +
geom_smooth()
```

So after reading several different post I added this to the code

```
geom_smooth(method = "loess",aes(x=DPV,y=Vac_1),inherit.aes=FALSE,se=FALSE)
```

which then creates a plot with the data smashed to the left
[image]

It is the correct trend line, however no the visual I was going for. I think the issue has something to due with the initial `ggplot(Vaccine1, aes(x= factor(DPV),y = VAC1))` becasue when I remove the factor I get the trend line over the data, but I do not get the per day results.
[image]

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I might correct this to get the trendline to overlay the individual day data? I am sure its a syntax issue that I am not seeing and if your fresh eyes can spot it please let me know!

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT** Please find the blinded data here for your reference

```
Tag #,Vac_1,DPV
1,28.65,3
2,28.83,3
3,27.67,3
4,28.51,3
5,25.87,3
6,28.75,3
7,27.24,3
8,27.82,3
9,30.03,3
10,28.56,3
11,24.24,6
12,23.66,6
13,26.98,6
14,26.14,6
15,24.52,6
16,26.11,6
17,27.99,6
18,23.78,6
19,25.08,6
20,23.43,6
21,29.69,9
22,28.5,9
23,27.43,9
24,27.59,9
25,25.85,9
26,26.11,9
27,26.18,9
28,25.7,9
29,27.89,9
30,26.4,9
31,26.78,12
32,24.87,12
33,28.39,12
34,29.51,12
35,28.55,12
36,26.61,12
37,29.09,12
38,26.64,12
39,29.37,12
40,29.38,12
41,29.74,15
42,32.55,15
43,30.25,15
44,29.99,15
45,29.88,15
46,30.14,15
47,31.57,15
48,28.25,15
49,28.85,15
50,30.17,15
51,26.78,18
52,24.87,18
53,28.39,18
54,29.51,18
55,28.55,18
56,26.61,18
57,29.09,18
58,26.64,18
59,29.37,18
60,29.38,18
61,37.15,21
62,31.32,21
63,34.33,21
64,33.48,21
65,32.2,21
66,32.58,21
67,32.45,21
68,36.02,21
69,35.69,21
70,35.86,21
71,32.05,24
72,30.6,24
73,32.72,24
74,32.49,24
75,34.71,24
76,40,24
77,35.46,24
78,35.02,24
79,31.42,24
80,36.27,24
81,38.5,27
82,35.42,27
83,34.75,27
84,40,27
85,32.22,27
86,34.06,27
87,35.95,27
88,35.92,27
89,30.68,27
90,40,27
91,38.21,30
92,30.29,30
93,33.16,30
94,37.81,30
95,38.44,30
96,34.69,30
97,35.19,30
98,36.39,30
99,30.06,30
100,36.59,30
```

Comment: It will be so much easier to help if you can provide a reproducible example. Otherwise for us to test we have to bring our own data and hope it has the same relevant properties as yours. My first guess would be to try `geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center",dotsize = .5, aes(group = DPV)) +`

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring that first guess is really close to what I am going for. The only issue I lost all the days making on the code you suggested.  It gives the clusters on a per day basis and the trendline fits where I wanted it to go but only labels days 10,20,30.

Comment: Also I blinded the test data and added it in a code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x_brk = unique(Vaccine1$DPV)
ggplot(Vaccine1, aes(x= DPV, y = Vac_1)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center",dotsize = .5, aes(group = DPV)) +
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_brk, minor_breaks = NULL) +
  expand_limits(y=c(15,40)) +
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

data

```
Vaccine1 <- data.frame(
         Tag = c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L,
                 11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L,17L,18L,19L,20L,21L,22L,23L,
                 24L,25L,26L,27L,28L,29L,30L,31L,32L,33L,34L,35L,36L,
                 37L,38L,39L,40L,41L,42L,43L,44L,45L,46L,47L,48L,
                 49L,50L,51L,52L,53L,54L,55L,56L,57L,58L,59L,60L,61L,
                 62L,63L,64L,65L,66L,67L,68L,69L,70L,71L,72L,73L,
                 74L,75L,76L,77L,78L,79L,80L,81L,82L,83L,84L,85L,86L,
                 87L,88L,89L,90L,91L,92L,93L,94L,95L,96L,97L,98L,99L,
                 100L),
       Vac_1 = c(28.65,28.83,27.67,28.51,25.87,28.75,
                 27.24,27.82,30.03,28.56,24.24,23.66,26.98,26.14,24.52,
                 26.11,27.99,23.78,25.08,23.43,29.69,28.5,27.43,27.59,
                 25.85,26.11,26.18,25.7,27.89,26.4,26.78,24.87,28.39,
                 29.51,28.55,26.61,29.09,26.64,29.37,29.38,29.74,32.55,
                 30.25,29.99,29.88,30.14,31.57,28.25,28.85,30.17,26.78,
                 24.87,28.39,29.51,28.55,26.61,29.09,26.64,29.37,29.38,
                 37.15,31.32,34.33,33.48,32.2,32.58,32.45,36.02,35.69,35.86,
                 32.05,30.6,32.72,32.49,34.71,40,35.46,35.02,31.42,
                 36.27,38.5,35.42,34.75,40,32.22,34.06,35.95,35.92,30.68,
                 40,38.21,30.29,33.16,37.81,38.44,34.69,35.19,36.39,
                 30.06,36.59),
         DPV = c(3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,6L,
                 6L,6L,6L,6L,6L,6L,6L,6L,6L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,9L,
                 9L,9L,9L,12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,12L,
                 15L,15L,15L,15L,15L,15L,15L,15L,15L,15L,18L,18L,
                 18L,18L,18L,18L,18L,18L,18L,18L,21L,21L,21L,21L,21L,
                 21L,21L,21L,21L,21L,24L,24L,24L,24L,24L,24L,24L,24L,
                 24L,24L,27L,27L,27L,27L,27L,27L,27L,27L,27L,27L,
                 30L,30L,30L,30L,30L,30L,30L,30L,30L,30L)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was going for! I am still figuring out which layers to add everything to so this will help me a lot! Thank you again for your help and time!